# Fuel\Core\PhpErrorException [ Notice ]: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: fuelphp

C:/wamp/www/bayadko/fuel/app/views/admin/parents/view.php @ line 1

This is my view.php

```
<h2>Viewing #<?php echo $parent->id; ?></h2>
<p>
   <strong>User id:</strong>
    <?php echo $parent->user_id; ?></p>
<p>
 <strong>Password:</strong>
 <?php echo $parent->password; ?></p>

<?php echo Html::anchor('admin/parents/edit/'.$parent->id, 'Edit'); ?> |
<?php echo Html::anchor('admin/parents', 'Back'); ?>
```

This is my index.php in view

```
  <?php foreach ($parents as $parent): ?>

  <h3><?php echo Html::anchor('admin/parents/view/'.$parent->user_id, $parent->password) ?></h3>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

My parents.php in classes/controller

```
public function action_index()
  {
     $data['parents'] = Model_Parent::find('all');
     $this->template->title = "Parents";
     $this->template->content = View::forge('admin/parents/index', $data);

  }
```

Comment: Hoping for someones help, I need to get rid of this one. tnx :)

Comment: I am now working with this site http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-an-admin-panel-with-the-fuel-php-framework--net-23186

Comment: well, you have the index action to feed the index view, do you have a function to actually send data to the single view template?

Comment: BTW I'd REALLY advise not following a 5 year old tutorial. Probably won't be any showstopping problems, but probably some issues for a beginner.

Comment: This One public function action_index()
    {
     $data['parents'] = Model_Parent::find('all');
     $this->template->title = "Parents";
     $this->template->content = View::forge('admin/parents/index',        $data);

  }

Comment: Nope, that's what feeds index.php, you also need one to get the correct parent you want to send to view.php.

Comment: This one        public function action_view($id = null)
 {
  $data['parent'] = Model_Parent::find($id);

  $this->template->title = "Parent";
  $this->template->content = View::forge('admin/parents/view', $data);

Comment: OK, so the error in your view is that $parent is a non-object. That probably means you query isn't working. Does var_dump()'ing $data['parent'] give you anything? If not, your query isn't working - so you probably aren't getting the $id value properly, and that's causing the query to crap out.

Comment: For many hours of brainstorming, I can't visualize wheres the problem is and the solution for this one, need help ;(

Comment: Did you try var_dump()'ing $data['parent'] to see if you actually get any results?